# Looking for a word or character in a file

Tags: java, file, loops, search

I'm trying to code a program that given a file with the names and addresses of five or more people, creates one different file (letter) for each of them (the new files will be named as the person who will receive it). 
The structure of the main file is something like this:

```
type1.0001 #n John Harrison #a Whatever Street, 490 - Liverpool
.... and so on
```

So "type1" is the type of letter this person has to be sent, the words after "#n" are the name, and the words after "#a" the address.

What I've been trying is this:

```
String datos = "main_file.txt";   
String tipo1 = "type1.txt";
String tipo2 = "type2.txt";
String tipo3 = "type3.txt";


char[] type1 = {'t', 'i', 'p', 'o', '1'};
//all other types should be here
String line;
FileReader fr = new FileReader("mainfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != ".") {
        char[] lineArray = line.toCharArray();
        if (lineArray == type1) {
            //code that creates file type1

        }
    }
}

fr.close();
```

So far this would just be the code that decides which letter to send, but it doesn't work. 
I think it's something related to the "while" loop.

Please, I started Java 1 month ago, so if anyone could help me I'd be so grateful!

Thanks

Right now,  I've got this:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("main_file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String nameMark = "#n";
        String addressMark = "#a";

        int nameStart = line.indexOf(nameMark) + nameMark.length();
        int addressStart = line.indexOf(addressMark) + addressMark.length();
        String name = line.substring(nameStart, addressStart - addressMark.length());
        String address = line.substring(addressStart, line.length());
        if (line.startsWith("tipo1.")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
            char[] vector = name.toCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            while (index < vector.length) {
                fw.write(vector[index]);
                index++;
            }
            fw.close();
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo2.")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
            char[] vector = name.toCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            while (index < vector.length) {
                fw.write(vector[index]);
                index++;
            }
            fw.close();

        }
    }

    fr.close();
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: you have two `readLine()` calls, so you fetch a line in the outside loop, then fetch ANOTHER line, throwing away the first line, with the second loop. so your outer loop will only ever fetch one line, which gets thrown away, then the inner loop will process the rest of the file, leaving nothing for the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Now how do I read the name and adress of each person?. I need both to include them in every new file

Comment: I edited my question, can someone check it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Marc B* told you, don't read the lines twice.

Also, just comparing the start of the line, will be much less overkill than you char array stuff.

To retrieve name and address, you could use `indexOf` and `substring` methods of [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Here is a whole example :

```
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // get the name and the address of this line
            String nameMark = "#n";
            String addressMark = "#a";

            int nameStart = line.indexOf(nameMark) + nameMark.length();
            int addressStart = line.indexOf(addressMark) + addressMark.length();

            String name = line.substring(nameStart, addressStart - addressMark.length());
            String address = line.substring(addressStart, line.length());

            // get the line type
            if (line.startsWith("tipo1")) {
                    //code that creates file type1 with name and address
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("tipo2")) {
                    //code that creates file type2 with name and address
            }
    ...
    ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Now how do I read the name and adress of each person?. I need both to include them in every new file.

Comment: I just added some example to retrieve your fields.

Comment: do i have to write this for every single person, or just once?

Comment: You write it only once in your loop, it will apply to each read line (see edited code) .

Comment: I'm trying to run it, but it gives me this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -15

Comment: Check the values of nameStart and addressStart .

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `==` with arrays. (Well, you can, but it doesn't do what you expect.) That is, this line is wrong:

```
  if (lineArray == type1)
```

Try `Arrays.equals` instead:

```
  if (Arrays.equals(lineArray, type1))
```

Comment: Are you really the author of [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Network-Programming-Third-Edition/dp/0596007213)?

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Now how do I read the name and adress of each person?. I need both to include them in every new file

Answer (score 0):

Try this for starters.

```
    String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("mainfile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // finish when line is null not "."

        String [] parts = line.split("#");

        String name, address;
        if (parts.length > 2) {
            name = parts[1].substring(2);
            address = parts[2].substring(2);
        }

        if (line.startsWith("tipo1")) {
            // save to tipo1 file
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo2")) {
            // save to tipo2 file
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo2")) {
            // save to tipo2 file
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo3")) {
            // save to tipo2 file
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo4")) {
            // save to tipo2 file
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo2")) {
            // save to tipo2 file
        }
    }

    fr.close();
```